# Which fuel is used by the Rebel cruisers in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, the Rebel cruiser runs low on fuel. What kind of fuel are they using?

Comment: I would imagine Star wars Fan tears

Answer (score 9):

Probably [Rhydonium](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rhydonium).  Its explored at much greater length in both animated TV shows. But basically its a volatile fuel found on the planet Abafar that can power starships. We don't really have many details beyond this in canon.

To be clear, this is different from the [hypermatter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hypermatter) that powers hyperdrives. Though they were low on that too.