# What type of reactor does The Raddus in SW:TLJ use for propulsion?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

What type of reactor does The Raddus in SW:TLJ use for propulsion? What type of fuel is it using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which fuel is used by the Rebel cruisers in The Last Jedi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176532/which-fuel-is-used-by-the-rebel-cruisers-in-the-last-jedi)

Comment: @amflare - Not a dupe. One is asking what fuel the ship uses, the other (this one) is asking about the means of propulsion. Since the engines are *ionic* those aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Valorum This question is asking _both_. </pedantry>

Answer (score 6):

The film's [Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) book indicates that the Raddus' sublight engines are *[ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster)* in nature. The ship evidently scoops up interstellar ions, accelerates them to a high velocity and then ejects them out of its enormous engines, creating thrust.

[image]

[image]

It stands to reason that the fuel (whatever it is) is therefore being used to create energy (to accelerate the ions) rather than directly burned. The earlier [Force Awakens: Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) factbook notes that almost all large ships use *hypermatter controlled fusion* as their primary power source.

[image]